# How to search record from db by selecting search category in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have list of record in my index page. Now i want to search a particular record/records by choosing the category (e.g phone No, email etc).How can i do this? help..

Here is my view:

```
    <?php
        $attributes = array('class'=>'searchform', 'id'=>'searchform');
        echo form_open('crud/searchCrud', $attributes);?>
        <div class="formelements">
            <div class="formlbl">
                Search:
            </div>
            <div class="forminput">
                <input type="text" name="searchon" id ="searchon"/>
            </div>
            <div class="searchtyp">
                <select class="searchby" name="searchby">
                    <option value="0">---Select--- </option>
                    <option value="name">Name</option>
                    <option value="email">Email</option>
                    <option value="phone">Phone</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="searchinput">
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </div>          
        <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Here is My controller:

```
    public function searchCrud()
    {
        $records =  $this->crud_mdl->searchCrud();
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            echo $record->name;
        }
    }
```

Here is My Model:

```
    public function searchCrud()
    {
        $searchby = $this->input->post('searchby');
        $searchon = $this->input->post('searchon');

        $this->db->get('test')->result();
        return $this->db->like($searchon, $searchby);
    }
```

Comment: do you need exact match for that search by and its necessary to check first if that record exist other wise you will get db errors

Comment: you shouldn't be echo-ing data in the controller

Comment: @Dan it's just for test purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should never access **`POST`** data directly in the **`Model`**.
2) Always collect them in **`Controller`** and then pass it to the **`Model`**.
3) Also always try to create your **`Model`** functions, **`re-usable`**.

Modified your code a bit. Try running it.

**Controller:**

```
public function searchCrud()
{
    $searchby = $this->input->post('searchby');
    $searchon = $this->input->post('searchon');

    $records =  $this->crud_mdl->searchCrud($searchby, $searchon);
    foreach ($records as $record) 
    {
        echo $record->name;
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function searchCrud($searchby, $searchon)
{
    $this->db->like($searchon, $searchby);
    $query = $this->db->get('test');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
         return $query->result();
    else
         return FALSE;
}
```